# How to share React state between component in Modal window and component on the background

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to find any tutorials, where described examples how to share Reat state between component in the modal window (based on React Router) and component, which is using as background location.

I even have no ideas what to use as starting point how to do that.

Any recommendations or links will be thankful!

Comment: Either prop-drilling, or use React context. I'd stick to a React context :)

Comment: You can use context API for state management. https://youtu.be/35lXWvCuM8o